# When using rqt with Qt5, does not find <QObject> in ROS internal "plugin_bridge.h"

Tags: ros, qt5, rqt, cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build the C++ example from the RQT tutorial, with a CMakeList and structure taken from rqt_image_view. I use Qt5 on Ubuntu with Cmake 2.8.12.2

When I run catkin_make everything in my project seems to run fine, but then it throws the following error.

```
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/qt_gui_cpp/plugin.h:36:0,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/rqt_gui_cpp/plugin.h:36,
             from my_catkin_ws/net_viz/include/net_viz/test.h:5
             from my_catkin_ws/net_viz/src/net_viz/test.cpp:1
/opt/ros/indigo/include/qt_gui_cpp/plugin_bridge.h:36:19: fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory
#include <QObject>
                  ^
```

It seems like it does not include Qt5 when linking with ros internal headers. Here is a gist of my CMakeLists.txt

http://pastebin.com/ac24neP5

This is a tarball of the full package.
https://mega.co.nz/#!lMs1iJBS!8sJXIgWfvvhSdP5CgDPHj68N4qil0A8CWXzysmSdo9Y

I don't know how to fix this, I thought about including qt5 explicitly, but it does get found right? And I also would not know where I can include it with the plugin_bridge.h

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197594/when-using-rqt-with-qt5,-does-not-find-%3Cqobject%3E-in-ros-internal-%22plugin_bridge.h%22/) by [igork](https://answers.ros.org/users/20839/igork/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rqt` currently only supports Qt 4.x.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1